# I don't receive the String I passed with an intent on my second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, error-handling

There is my *Take all my time when I need to hurry* problem..

I just make an intent to travel informations from my main to an other activity.
But the data don't go to the other activity.

Pick an eye just some second please.

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String KEY = "KEY";
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(KEY, "FONCTIONNE");

        startActivity(intent);

        });
    }
}
```

### OtherActivity.class

```
import static com.example.marguerite.experiences.MainActivity.KEY;

public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
TextView textView;
String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

        text = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY);

        textView.setText(text);

        button.setOnClickListener(v ->finish());
    }
}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.marguerite.experiences">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

### ERROR EVENT

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.marguerite.experiences, PID: 8496
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marguerite.experiences/com.example.marguerite.experiences.OtherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.marguerite.experiences.OtherActivity.onCreate(OtherActivity.java:26)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
```

There it is. I certainly forgot something but all tutorials I have looked about use the same easy technique.

Comment: Please post `activity_other.xml`. Looks like the `TextView` does not exist there.

Comment: change the textview id to the actual one. I think copy paste error

Answer (score 1):

The following line...

```
textView.setText(text);
```

... provokes the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

which means that `textView` is null. There is no view with id `textview` in `activity_other.xml`. Make sure that the view exists and rule out any typos.

See also: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yeah, thanks you for your help. I need this to ensure my self this was the good technic, i work on an other application and use the same but it would'nt work. I copy/past this one once the code was corrected and it worked so thank you ! The problem of the other wasn't a missing id, i'll never know tho ...

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers should work but if still not working try changing

```
 button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

to

```
 button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

in both activities

and when you get the intent in OtherActivity call it like

```
text = getIntent.getStringExtra("KEY");
```